# Better alternative for comma separated field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my application whenever a user upload a wallpaper,i need to crop that wallpaper into 
3 different sizes and store all those paths(3 paths for cropped images  and 1 for original upload wallpaper) into my database.
I also need to store the tinyurl of the original wallpaper(one which is uploaded by user).

While solving the above described problem i come up with following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `wallpapermaster` (
  `wallpaperid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `wallpaperloc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `wallpapertitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `wallpaperstatus` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-Waiting,1-approved,2-disapproved',
  `tinyurl` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

wallpaperloc is a comma separated field consisting of original wallpaper location plus locations of all cropped instances.

I know using comma separated field considered to be a bad design in the world of   relational database,So Would you like to suggest some other neat and efficient ways?

Comment: Using XML would lend more structure & reliability than a comma-separated list IMO.

Comment: What exactly is a "wallpaper location"? An ID? A text describing where it came from? A URL?

Comment: wallpaper location refer to path on server where the wallpaper is located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a 1:n relationship between the wallpapermaster and a location table.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE wallpapermaster (
  wallpaperid     int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userid          bigint NOT NULL,
  wallpaperloc    varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  wallpapertitle  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  wallpaperstatus tinyint DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-Waiting,1-approved,2-disapproved',
  primary key (wallpaperid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE wallpaperlocation (
  wallpaperid  int unsigned NOT NULL,
  location     varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  tinyurl      varchar(40),
  constraint fk_loc_wp 
      foreign key (wallpaperid) 
      references wallpapermaster (wallpaperid),
   primary key (wallpaperid, location)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The primary key in `wallpaperlocation` ensures that the same location cannot be inserted twice.

Note that `int(10)` does not define any datatype constraints. It is merely a *hint* for client application to indicate how many digits the number has.

Comment: Thanks for good answer, i would like to ask few question.Why did you choose InnoDB instead of myisam here,What if i have to specify tinyurl for only one specific sized crop image(540*320) then should i consider making that column into wallpaperlocation table(since then this column going to consist of lots of null value).

Comment: I chose InnoDB to be able to setup a foreign key. I can't imagine any reason to still use MyISAM nowadays. Does the tinyurl belong to a location or to a wallpaper?

Comment: tinyurl belongs to a location(where wallpaper stored on server)

Comment: @Tarun: then it should go into wallpaperlocation. I wouldn't worry about the null values.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use a fixed location (maybe out of a config), fix extension (usually `jpg`) and a special filename formats like `[name]-1024x768.jpg`. This way you only the the name

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion using `;` or `,` in **siple application** is quite good solution even in relational databases.

You should propably think about amout of splitted images count. If there will be less than 5 wallpapers I would not take overhead complex solutions.

- It's easy to maintain in database and application. You will use string `splitting/joining` methods
- **No need to adding extra additional tables** which you will use `join` to retreive values.
- Using simple `varchar` rather `xml` is better because you don't have to rely on application database access engine. When you use **ORM** or **JDBC** you have extra additional work to do to handle more complex datatypes.

In more **complex** systems I would make `XML` column.

Answer (score 1):

While thumbnails are generated automatically from the single uploaded file, you don't need to store paths to cropped/resized files at all.

Instead you can just use normalized filenames for thumbnails  and then find them in filesystem - something that KingCrunch suggested: `photo1.jpg`, `photo1-medium.jpg` etc.

Anyway, my 2cc: for avoiding traversing your image library (and created thumbnails) with some harvesters, it's good idea to encrypt name of each thumbnail even with just MD5 + some secret key programmatically, so only your program which knows the key can create proper path to the thumbnails basing on the original name/path. For other clients, naming sequence will be just random.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `wallpapermaster` (
  `wallpaperid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `wallpapertitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `wallpaperstatus` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-Waiting,1-approved,2-disapproved',
  `tinyurl` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Create a new table which will create relationship with "wallpapermaster" table

```
create wallpapermaster_mapper( 
    `id` unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `wallpapermaster_id` int(10) //this will be foreign key with id of wallpapermaster table
    `wallpaper_path1`  varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `wallpaper_path2`  varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `wallpaper_path3`  varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    )
```

Comment: That is not very normalized (and column names should not be enclosed in single quotes - if at all double quotes or those dreaded backticks).